# write an ng-pattern to disallow whitespaces and special characters

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am trying to get an angular ng-pattern to check that a username has no whitespaces or special characters. The following form return false if you enter whitespaces or special characters. However, it becomes true as soon as you enter a-z, A-z or 0-9. I have tried ng-pattern="/[^\s]+/" and \S and [^ ] but they make no difference.

```
<form name="myform">
  valid? {{ myform.$valid }}
  <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9^ ]/" required/>
</form>
```

Here's the form in a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/6T78kyUgXYfNAwB4RHKQ?p=preview

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

This allows only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! A note: before angular version 1.1.0, the model is trimmed so adding a space before or after the string will not return false.

Comment: @CraigMorgan You are welcome. I don't work with Angular at all, but I know it is a Javascript library and I provided you with a valid Javascript regular expression :)

Comment: Just to add to this. Angular will trim the input model, meaning that the validation doesn't trigger for spaces. You can add an `ng-trim="false"` to the input to fix this.

Answer (score 14):

To surface the specific answer I was looking for, I already had the pattern suggested by Sniffer `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`, but angular still appeared to ignore leading/trailing whitespace. As [Cristian mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423827/write-an-ng-pattern-to-disallow-whitespaces-and-special-characters#comment42520349_19424059) in the comments:

> Angular will trim the input model, meaning that the validation doesn't trigger for spaces. You can add an `ng-trim="false"` to the input to fix this.

Note that Angular is trying to protect you by silently trimming whitespace by default. In my case, I want the user to be aware that the trailing whitespace is invalid.

Comment: your ng-trim helped me a lot because inside angular it is needed to avoid whitespace

Comment: agreed! nice tip. i would have gone the regex approach, which is not as nice as this since in need to trim the whitespace anyway. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

in case anyone needs to disallow user entering emails in the address field

ng-pattern="/^[^@]+$/"

```
<div ng-messages="vm.updateCC.mailingAddress.$error" ng-show="vm.updateCC.mailingAddress.$touched">
     <p class="validation-message" ng-message="pattern">Please enter a valid address</p>
</div>
```