# ng pattern which allows alphanumeric but without spaces for input tag in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

am using the patterns like "/[a-zA-Z0-9][^\s]/" and "/\s/" but no one is working. can you give any solution for this "ng pattern for input tag and which allows oly alphanumeric but it does not allow spaces in the input field ".

Answer (score 3):

Try the following pattern: /^\s*\w*\s*$/

```
<script>
   angular.module('textInputExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.text = 'guest';
       $scope.word = /^\s*\w*\s*$/;
     }]);
 </script>
 <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   Single word: <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="text" ng-maxlength="5"
                       ng-pattern="word" required ng-trim="">
```

[Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fVgyH7HkEc6kSqt71sXi?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/ruqet/1/edit

```
   <form name="myform">
        <input type="text" ng-model="val" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" name="abc"/>
        <br/>
        <span ng-show="myform.abc.$error.pattern">Please use numbers letters only</span>
      </form>
```

Comment: But it does not display error message when we enter space into the text box. This is for alphanumeric [a-zA-Z0-9] working but the input field does not accept spaces.

Comment: @swapna you can add required please see updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/ruqet/2/edit

Comment: This pattern works if you also add `ng-trim="false"` to the input. See this duplicate question/answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424059/7032554

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="testFrm">
            <input type="text" ng-model="val" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/" name="value"/>
            <span ng-show="testFrm.value.$error.pattern">Please use numbers and letters only</span>
          </form>
```