# Negate certain symbols input by user from a search field using angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

For instance, if I have a search function that searches through hashtags (#), and people (@), what is the best way to deal with the case when people actually type in that character i.e:

`SEARCH:  @sally` or
`SEARCH: #trendyTag`

instead of:

`SEARCH: sally` or `SEARCH: trendyTag`

The particular `label` and `input` tags I'm using have a placeholder as well of course, but I don't want to count on users reading or paying attention to that. As it stands now, if they type in a symbol their results don't get returned, so I implemented a cheap hack that just accepts the particular symbol for each different category but I'm hoping there's a better way to do this in angular.

Answer (score 0):

I made an [example form in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkMrAHBB63moaTwCJYEm?p=preview) based on an [earlier SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423827/write-an-ng-pattern-to-disallow-whitespaces-and-special-characters).

The sample uses Angular's built-in form validation features, especially the `pattern` attribute to validate a text input by a regular expression match.  You might want to revise the regular expression to better match your scenario.

```
<form name="searchForm">
  <div>
    <label for="editSearchTerms" class="control-label">Search</label>
    <input 
      type="text" 
      id="editSearchTerms" 
      name="searchTerms" 
      placeholder="hashtag or people"
      ng-model="terms"
      pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
      required
      /> 
    <button ng-click="search(terms)" ng-disabled="searchForm.$invalid">Go</button>
  </div>
  <p class="invalid" ng-show="searchForm.$invalid && !searchForm.$pristine">
    The characters '@' and '#' are not allowed.
  </p>
```